# Не могу устранить ошибку c#(unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю проект уже продолжительное время и вот в один момент, кнопка дебага проекта изменилась на "Пуск" вместо "Подключить к unity", и при нажатии выскакивает ошибка.

[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC87Q.jpg][1]][1]

Почитал в Гугле ответы насчёт этой ошибки, что-то попробовал, но ничего не помогло. Вот пришел просить помощи здесь.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU4nU.jpg)

Comment: Может есть какие то другие способы ее решения? Ничего не получается

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь запустить ваш код в Visual Studio, это невозможно, так как это просто набор классов. Игры Unity нужно запускать в редакторе Unity.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы включить режим отладки, нажав на кнопку в Visual Studio, убедитесь, что в самом Unity включен режим отладки. Он обозначен картинкой жука.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но у меня жук все время был включён

Comment: @qwix возможно вы открыли Visual Studio не из Unity, и это как то повлияло?

Comment: Не, я делал все как обычно, заходил в unity, запускал скрипт, а там такая напасть приключилась.